# Using properties of a function that has yet to be shown to exist?

Tags: measure-theory, problem-solving

Check if a function $f : \mathscr P(\Bbb R) \rightarrow [0, \infty[$ exists with the following properties:

$i) \ f(\emptyset) = 0,$

$ii) \ f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k)$ = $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(A_k)$ for disjoint sets $A_k$,

$iii) \ f(A + c) = f(A)$ for every $A \subset \Bbb R$ and $c \in \Bbb R,$

$iv)  \ f([0, 1]) = 1.$

Do it the following way:

> We want to call $x$ and $y$ equivalent iff $x - y \in \Bbb Q$ for $x, y \in [0, 1].$ We choose exactly one representative from every equivalence class. Let $V \subset [0, 1]$ be the set of every representative that we chose before.
>
> Now let $\{q_1, q_2, \ ... \}$ be an enumeration of every rational number in $[-1, 1]$. Show that the sets
>
> $V_k := q_k + V := \{q_k + v:  v \in V \}, k \in \Bbb N$
>
> are disjoint to each other.

That was the first task. I have no question about that one, but about the second task:

> Show that
>
> $1 \le f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k) \le 3.$

What buggs me is the fact that we are actually supposed to show that this function $f$ does exist. There is even a last step where we are required to conclude it.

Now, I'm not sure whether I have to use the properties defined before or not. I wouldn't assume so, but since the function doesn't have any other properties, I'd guess that I have to do it.

Comment: What is *the first task*? This question is not very clear.

Comment: Put it in the main post.

Comment: ... and wrote the task much clearer, hope that helps. Sorry about the mess before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show, that such a fuction $f$ does not exist, you suppose to the contrary that such a function exists. Then its your turn to derive a contradiction.

Comment: But I don't intent to show that is does not exist.

Comment: But what they're doing is having you derive properties of a hypothetical such function in order to conclude that such properties do not allow $f$ to exist. Essentially, yes, showing that $f$ doesn't exist is the end game here.

Comment: So I do have to use those properties then?

Comment: Yes, what else ?